# GridView with CKEDITOR using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

So I have a web site that uses a main GridView with `CKEDITOR`.

Don't have problem if I use `CKEDITOR` for edit the string on the texbox. The string it's formatted correctly.

The problem i'ts the output of the string in GridView when I close the editing.

The strings don't wrap as expected in `CKEDITOR` and there is no space between one string and another.

I have tried using this code, but the output of the string in GridView displays the `HTML` code.

I need show in GridView the same formatting that you see when editing the string in `CKEDITOR`.

This is HTML code

In editing gridview row the string it's formatted correctly.

Closed the editing row the gridview does not respect the formatting and show the strings on a single line.

```
<td align="left">
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvProducts_ctl04_lbsezi" class="LabelJustifyTextStyle" style="padding:20px;">
<ul>
<li>        
<strong>First</strong>
</li>  
</ul>  
<p style="margin-left: 30pt; text-align: justify;">     
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>  
<ul>
<li>        
<strong>Second</strong>
</li> 
</ul>  
<p style="margin-left: 40px; text-align: justify;">     
The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>  
</td>
```

Thanks for any advice.

```
<asp:Label ID="lb" runat="server" CssClass="LabelJustifyTextStyle"
     Text='<%# Eval("lb").ToString().Contains("base64") ?
     HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("lb").ToString()) :
     HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Mp.SpliceText(Eval("lb").ToString(),150)) %>'></asp:Label>
 
    public static string SpliceText(string text, int lineLength)
    {
        var charCount = 0;
        var lines = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .GroupBy(w => (charCount += w.Length + 1) / lineLength)
                        .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g));
 
        return String.Join("<br />", lines.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: use `Literal` and not `Label`.

Comment: @Aristos thanks for suggestion, but the problem remains

Comment: Its then difficult to understand where the real problem is. Maybe is where the CKEditor returns the data, maybe is how the gridview renders the data, maybe is on `EVAL()` and you need there to make a call to code behind...

Comment: see that answer and replace your EVAL() and the Label https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615953/asp-net-databound-string-column-format/69616237#69616237